# Passport js local strategy is not being called

Tags: node.js, passport.js, mean

this is my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

//Mongodb connection
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/expressWithAngular")
.then(() => {
    console.log("mongodb connected");
})

//bodyparser middleware 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//load routes
const users = require("./routes/users");

//include passport
require("./config/passport")(passport);



// use routes
app.use('/user' , users);



app.get('' ,(req,res) => {
    res.send('home');
})

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port   , () => {
    console.log(`server is running in port ${port}`);
})
```

this is my user routes routes/user.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');


//user model init
require('./../models/User');
const User = mongoose.model('users');

router.post('/login' , (req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("bodyparser" ,req.body);
    passport.authenticate('local',{
        session: false
    },function(req,res,next){
        console.log(res);
    })
})
```

module.exports = router;

this is my config/passport.js

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

module.exports = function(passport){
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        {
            usernameField : 'email'
        },
       function(email,password,done){
           console.log(email);
       }
    ))
}
```

- i was trying to connect my mean stack app with passport
   authentication, i am able to send details to backend but i couldn't
   pass the value to local strategy
 - I don't know where i am missing, when i consoled the local strategy is
   not called, please correct me where i am missing

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have problem in your router configuration. `passport.authenticate` is [generating middleware](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/882d65e69d5b56c6b88dd0248891af9e0d80244b/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L70) for you, but in your case you have wrapped it in function so you could log input parameters and you haven't returned generated middleware to router:

```
router.post('/login' , (req,res,next)=>{
  console.log("bodyparser" ,req.body);
  passport.authenticate('local',{
    session: false
  },function(req,res,next){
    console.log(res);
  })
})
```

I would advise you to modify your code to work like in example in official documentation:

```
router.post('/login' , passport.authenticate('local',{
        session: false
    });
)
```

If you really need to log `req.body` just add a middleware before authentication like this:

```
router.post('/login' , (req, res, next) {
      console.log("bodyparser" ,req.body);
      next();
    },
    passport.authenticate('local', {session: false});
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turns out that the function is not called when it does not receive the correct parameters.
First make sure that in the **req.body** are the data properly. Then, if you use [localStrategy](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/), this strategy requires ***two parameters*** that are username and password. But it is only receiving the ***usernameField*** as email. The ***passwordField*** parameter must be specified,

```js
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField : 'email',
  //here will be the name of the password field in your form
  passwordField : 'userPassword'
}))
```

Only then can the local strategy be invoked. By default `localStrategy` is looking for the values 'username' and 'password'